# Как можно ускорить код проверки, что из букв первой строки можно создать вторую строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть две строки. Если буквы из второй строки совпадают с буквами из первой строки тогда True иначе False. Короче чтобы из букв первой строки можно было составить слово из второй строки.

```
def scramble(s1, s2):

    for x in s1:
        if s2.find(x) != -1:
            s2 = s2.replace(x, '', 1)
            
       
    if len(s2)==0:
        return print(True)
    else:
        return print(False)
            
scramble('rkqodlw', 'world')
```

Comment: буквы из второй строки должны быть в первой тогда True

Comment: Есть две строки.  Если буквы из второй строки  совпадают с буквами из первой строки тогда True иначе False. Короче чтобы из букв первой строки можно было составить слово из второй строки.

Comment: И можно ли его ускорить?

Comment: Если буквы не могут повторяться, то достаточно сравнить set(s1) и set(s2)

Comment: Могут повторяться!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Создаём словарь со счётчиками символов второй строки. Для каждого символа из первой уменьшаем соотв. счётчик. В конце смотрим, чтобы не осталось ненулевых счётчиков. Сложность примерно линейная `O(len(s1)+len(s2))`

```
from collections import Counter
def sc1(s1, s2):
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return True
    cnt = Counter(s2)
    for x in s1:
        if cnt[x]:
            cnt[x] -= 1
    return cnt.most_common(1)[0][1]==0
```

Ещё проще, как подсказал extrn, выполнить сравнение Counter - для версии Python >= 3.10

```
def scr(s1, s2):
    return Counter(s2) <= Counter(s1)
```

Вариант с сортировкой, сложность `O(len1*log(len1)+len2*log(len2))`

```
def sc2(s1, s2):
    l1 = sorted(list(s1))
    l2 = sorted(list(s2))
    i1, i2 = 0, 0
    while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
        if l1[i1]==l2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        elif l1[i1] > l2[i2]:
            return False
        else:
            i1 += 1
    return i2 == len(l2)
```

Comment: return cnt.most_common(1)[0][1]==0
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range ноль в скобках подчеркивает

Comment: Посмотрите (print), что лежит в объекте `cnt` и что в  `cnt.most_common(1)`. Я не проверял с пустыми строками - это нужно обработать отдельно

Comment: Второй работает. Спасибо!

Comment: В первый добавил проверку пустоты s2. Не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @MBo для Counter [корректно реализовано сравнение](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L808). `Counter('est') >= Counter('test')` и `Counter('estt') >= Counter('test')`. `False` и `True` соответственно.

Comment: @extrn Спасибо, добавил до кучи. У меня Python 3.7, это было недоступно.

Comment: @MBo мне почему-то казалось, что пользовался этим и значительно раньше. Видимо все таки показалось.

Comment: @extrn Там это просто чуть по-другому делалось

Answer (score 2):

Для более старых версий питона можно вычесть `Counter`-ы слов и проверить, что получилась пустая коллекция:

```
from collections import Counter

def scramble(s1, s2):
    return not (Counter(s2) - Counter(s1))

print(scramble('приветствие', 'твист'))
print(scramble('приветствие', 'истец'))
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
```